# How to remove price from Woocommerce Email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to develop a plugin that send the customer a "gift receipt" upon completing an order.  I have everything working perfectly except I am unable to strip the price from the emails.  When I try to edit the email-order-items.php template and remove the price column then the emails come in blank.

Specifically this is for downloadable products so the download links no longer show when I make any edits to the email-order-items file.  And I would only want it to strip the price from the gift receipt emails not the other emails.

What I have done:
in my plugin I call on a email template "customer-gift-receipt.php" which is pretty much the same as "customer-processing-order.php" that comes package with Woocommerce.

In the file there is this line that brings in the email-order-items template and shows the links and price

```
<?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( $order->is_download_permitted(), 
     true, ($order->status=='processing') ? true : false ); ?>
```

[This is the email-order-items template.](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-order-items.php)

No matter what I do I cannot seem to get those prices stripped from just the `customer-gift-receipt.php` emails. Specifically it is this line in the above template:

```
<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;">
    <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>
</td>
```

I tried creating a duplicate of the email-order-items template and removing that line then calling it in my plugin and that did not work.  I also tried copying the email-order-items template inside of the `customer-gift-receipt.php` file in the appropriate section and that failed as well. I had to define `$items = $order->get_items();` when I tried copying `email-order-items` directly into the `customer-gift-receipt` template for it to somewhat work.

So can anyone suggest a way for me to strip the prices out of my customer-gift-receipt templates?

I have checked through these links:

[Class WC_Order](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html)

[Class WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order.html)

---

**UPDATE:**
I just found this link which should help me bring in `email_order_items_table` outside of the class: https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/1965842
When I try to add the above code in my `customer-email-receipt` template and place an order I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'order_item_meta' not found in 
   .../.../.../.../woocommerce/emails/customer-gift-receipt.php on line 41"
```

Comment: you don't have to remove it.  Just set it to display:none in the inine style

Comment: I thought of that and would love for it to be that easy, however by doing so it will display none on ALL emails that use that file.  I just need it to not display for the gift receipt emails.  Until now I thought I had to work directly with email-order-items.php file but the updated section in my question shows a way for me to get that order table outside of its class so I can remove the price directly in my template, only I am now getting the fatal error specified in updated section of question.  How could I get it to display none just for gift receipt emails? That is my ultimate goal anyway

Comment: theres probably some variable available to indicate its a gift receipt.  Add the display none when thats present

Comment: Thank you Rooster, I wonder how I could resolve that Fatal Error with Class 'order_item_meta' not being found in my template?  It is declared in Woocommerce already so what should I do to fix that so I could have more control over the gift receipt order table? Here is my customer-email-receipt template.  The error says it is from line 40 where I declare the new class( and apparently it cannot find the original) http://pastebin.com/E2d3ifHR

Comment: the classes source isn't included

Answer (score 1):

Disable e-mail order items table from e-mail template and copy the function as a custom function into your theme.

```
<tbody>
    <?php //echo $order->email_order_items_table( $order->is_download_permitted(), true, ($order->status=='processing') ? true : false ); 
    echo custom_order_table($order);
    ?>
</tbody>
```

I had to remove download and variations which causes *Fatal Error with Class 'order_item_meta'* error. So your custom function will look like:

```
       function custom_order_table($order,$price = false) {

        foreach($order->get_items() as $item) : 

        $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

        $file = $sku = $variation = $image = '';

        if ($show_image) :
          $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $_product->id ), 'thumbnail');
          $image = apply_filters('woocommerce_order_product_image', '<img src="'.$src[0].'" alt="Product Image" height="'.$image_size[1].'" width="'.$image_size[0].'" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px;" />', $_product);
        endif;

        if ($show_sku && $_product->get_sku()) :
          $sku = ' (#' . $_product->get_sku() . ')';
        endif;


        $return .= '<tr>
          <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;">'. $image . apply_filters('woocommerce_order_product_title', $item['name'], $_product) . $sku . $file . $variation . '</td>
          <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;">'.$item['qty'].'</td>';
        if ($price):
          $return .= '<td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;">';

            if ( $order->display_cart_ex_tax || !$order->prices_include_tax ) : 
              $ex_tax_label = ( $order->prices_include_tax ) ? 1 : 0;
              $return .= woocommerce_price( $order->get_line_subtotal( $item ), array('ex_tax_label' => $ex_tax_label ));
            else :
              $return .= woocommerce_price( $order->get_line_subtotal( $item, true ) );
            endif;

          $return .= '</td>';
        endif;
        $return .= '</tr>';

        // Show any purchase notes
        if ($show_purchase_note) :
          if ($purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note', true)) :
            $return .= '<tr><td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;">' . apply_filters('the_content', $purchase_note) . '</td></tr>';
          endif;
        endif;

      endforeach;

      echo $return;
      }
```